# Running code built for x86 unpaged protected mode

Tags: x86, paging, reverse-engineering, qemu, protected-mode

I'm currently trying to reverse engineer a program (~30KB, mostly code) that appears to be built for x86 **unpaged protected mode**. It contains instructions that access physical memory (or memory mapped device registers to be more precise) directly, e.g.:

```
mov esi, 0FED400000h ; Some device base address
mov eax, [esi+18h]   ; Memory mapped status register of said device
```

I would like to run said program in **QEMU** and ideally be able to step through it in a debugger such as gdb.

Now the problem is that the absolute memory addresses encoded in the code result in segmenation faults in any operating system with paging enabled.

I've been thinking of ways to circumvent this:

- Map physical memory into user space by using mmap on /dev/mem and run the program in user space. While this allows access to physical memory, the hardcoded memory addresses in the analyzed program would need to be patched as the mapped address will not be the same as the physical address. This seems hardly feasible due to the large amount of encoded absolute addresses.
- Install a segmentation fault handler that tries to fix the illegal memory access by rewriting the address. Then run the program in user space.
- Write a bootloader that loads the program code from disk into memory, enters protected mode (including setup of the GDT) and jumps to it. As I've never written any comparable code, I'm not even sure this would work.

Are there any other options to run this program I've missed so far? Or do you have any suggestions, additions or experiences with the ideas mentioned above?

Comment: What format is it? DOS COM, EXE, Win32 PE?

Comment: It is a TXT authenticated code module (aka SINIT ACM) from Intel (see [TXT Software Development Guide](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/software-developers/intel-txt-software-development-guide.html) page 64ff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The few SINIT modules I've seen have a small <strike>real-mode</strike> loader part at the entry which parses and jumps into a plain PE file embedded at the end of the module. So, if you don't need to debug the loader, you can extract the PE and then use one of the DOS extenders which support PE files (e.g. HX-DOS, WDOSX) to load and debug it from DOS. Note, however, that the private TXT registers won't be accessible once the module has run and issued the CLOSE-PRIVATE command.

BTW, the 0xFED40000 range seems to belong to Intel's internal TPM (iTPM). See `tpm_tis` driver in Linux. So you could instead intercept these accesses (with a signal/exception handler) and redirect them to an actual TPM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the hint at the embedded PE file. Unfortunately I'll have to debug the loader as well since I'd like to know which TXT/TPM registers it accesses and which TPM commands it executes. I'm also not sure whether you've seen this particular SINIT module before: The code does not look like 16 bit real mode code to me as it accesses 32 bit registers like `eax`, `ecx` etc. without an operand size prefix (0x66).

Comment: Yes, apparently I'm wrong about "real-mode". The loader code will use the selector from the GDT specified in the header and it seems Intel's modules default to 32-bit CS.